# get first column in array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet and need to get the values (email addresses) of a certain column, which is C in this case. Let's assume there are three emails in the column. The log gives me:

"[[email1], [email2], [email3]]"

In order to continue with the script I need to have the array looking like this:

"[email1, email2, email3]"

So just without the outer brackets. I know I can target just "[email1]" by adding "[0]" behind ".getValues()". I tried something like "[[all]]" but it didn't work. What do I have to change?
I know, this is probably pretty basic but I'm an absolute beginner, thankful for any help.

```
function myFunction() {

  // Variables
  var id = "ID";
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var inputSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("inputSheet");
  var inputLR = inputSheet.getLastRow();
  var emailsAll = inputSheet.getRange(2, 3, inputLR).getValues();

  Logger.log(emailsAll);
}
```

Comment: I think that you can also use ``var r = [].concat.apply([], emailsAll)``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### V8 update(ES6):

Use [Array#flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
var em = emailsAll.flat();//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
```

---

Try [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or `Array#forEach`

```
var em = emailsAll.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
```

Answer (score 2):

`getValues()` return a two-dimensional array representing the rows and columns in the range. 
Read more in the [developer reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

Iterate over this array to access the values.

```
for(var row=0;row<emailsAll.length;row++){
   for(var col=0;col<emailsAll[row].length;col++){
      var cellValue = emailsAll[row][col];
      Logger.log(cellValue);
   }
}
```

Reference material about `for` loops [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Example in plain js:

```js
var emailsAll = [["email1"],["email2"],["email3"]];
for(var row=0;row<emailsAll.length;row++){
  for(var col=0;col<emailsAll[row].length;col++){
    var cellValue = emailsAll[row][col];
    console.log(cellValue);
  }
}
```