# Compare two arrays, get rows numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to break where I want to get to apart into smaller steps and questions so I can understand it better. I turned two columns (each containing email addresses, each from different sheets) into two 1D arrays ([answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895524/get-first-column-in-array/52896640#52896640)), that I now want to compare for matches. I want to know which of the values in the "emailsPaidArray" are also in the "emailsAllArray". More exact I need the row numbers from the matches in "sheetAll" (as 1D array, e.g. "rowsYesMatch") as well as the row numbers of the ones that don't match (also as 1D array, e.g. "rowsNotMatch").

It has to be done by script and NOT by formula. I think it will be some kind of loop but this is all new to me. I have no coding skills and am very thankful for help and simple answers.

```
function paymentStatus() {

  // Variables

  var id = "ID";
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheetAll = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("sheetAll");
  var sheetPaid = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("sheetPaid");
  var sheetOutput = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("sheetOutput");
  var allLR = sheetAll.getLastRow();
  var paidLR = sheetPaid.getLastRow();

  // get tow 1D arrays

  var emailsAll = sheetAll.getRange(2, 3, allLR).getValues();
  var emailsPaid = sheetPaid.getRange(2, 1, paidLR).getValues();

  var emailsAllArray = emailsAll.map(function(e) {return e[0];} );
  // Logger.log(emailsAllArray);

  var emailsPaidArray = emailsPaid.map(function(e) {return e[0];} );
  // Logger.log(emailsPaidArray);

  // compare two arrays

  // get rows
```

Looks like this:
[image: sheetAll]
[image: sheetPaid]

Comment: In order to understand correctly about your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? I think that it will help users think of about your issue. Of course, please remove your personal information from it.

Comment: I uploaded two pictures, hope that help to explain? When I have the rows then I can continue and copy only the paid ones from sheetAll over to sheetOutput and also can add another column to sheetAll that marks the rows as "paid" or "unpaid". But first I want to understand the loop that compares the two arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I ask you about the result that you want from the 2 pictures? In the case of the sample, you want email3 and email6. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The result I need to get are the rows in "sheetAll" that contain the email addresses that match with those in "sheetPaid". In the pictures this would result in rows 2, 3, 5, 6

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this script? I noticed that I misunderstand your question. So I updated it.

```
var res = emailsAllArray.map(function(e, i) {return emailsPaidArray.some(function(f) {return e == f}) ? i + 2 : ""}).filter(Number);
// [2,3,5,6]
```

You can also use this script.

```
var res = emailsAllArray.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
  if (emailsPaidArray.some(function(f) {return e == f})) ar.push(i + 2);
  return ar;
},[]);
// [2,3,5,6]
```

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

### Edit:

If you want to retrieve the row numbers of the difference values, please use this.

```
var res = emailsAllArray.map(function(e, i) {return emailsPaidArray.some(function(f) {return e == f}) ? "" : i + 2}).filter(Number);
// [4,7]
```

or

```
var res = emailsAllArray.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
  if (!emailsPaidArray.some(function(f) {return e == f})) ar.push(i + 2);
  return ar;
},[]);
// [4,7]
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the values of the duplicates/matches and differences/non-matches. What I need are the rows in which those values are.

Comment: @hupfhupf Yes. I noticed it. So I updated my answer. Can you reload your browser? If I misunderstand what you want, please tell me.

Comment: it looks really good now, both scripts do work! just trying to figure out now how to get the other part of the rows as well (the ones that don't match) [4,7]

Comment: @hupfhupf I added a script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: This is really good, all works perfectly fine and it is just a tiny bit of code. Thanks you so much. The references at the mozilla page are very good as well, thanks a lot!

Comment: @hupfhupf I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for an elegant solution.
But I had a difficulty.
I can to retrieve the row numbers of the difference values and I get [4,7]. However, when I try to retrieve the row numbers of the matching values, I get [2,3,5,6,8] instead of [2,3,5,6].
Could you take a look at the script, please? I want to understand where I went wrong.
[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11_2f29pPD2wafsyfgBA1hOQMmS0SF1LmVo-USqJSJcc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Boris Baublys Thank you for your comment. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But about your new question, I cannot understand. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, users can think of your new question. Also I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank. I figured out the error. Everything works if we subtract 1 from the allLR in getRange. It should be like this: var emailsAll = sheetAll.getRange(2, 3, allLR - 1).getValues(); Thank you also for your detailed and respectful SO responses. They are very helpful.