# Google Sheets Function to clone Column A of 1 sheet to Column A of another Sheet as plain text and no formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a function that copies my data sheet called 7705-CONFIG over to a new sheet called EXPORT with no formulas which is what I want. It then runs through the EXPORT sheet to remove all blank rows. The request I have is how to have the copy of the 7705-CONFIG to the EXPORT Sheet not clone the entire sheet but just what is in column A. On the 7705-CONFIG Sheet I have in Column B explanations for what each of the formulas is doing. If it would just clone Column A of the 7705-CONFIG sheet to EXPORT sheet that would be most helpful. Also my current code deletes the EXPORT sheet each time it runs and then creates a new EXPORT sheet. If there is a clean way to clear the contents on the EXPORT sheet without deleting and creating it in the copy process that would be nice. Thanks in advance for your time and support!

```
function copyCONFIGtoEXPORT() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var deleteEXPORT = ss.getSheetByName("EXPORT");// get the sheet object
  ss.deleteSheet(deleteEXPORT);// done !  
  Browser.msgBox("Export Configs Started", "This process takes a around 7 min to delete all the blank rows from ports configs not in use. You'll get a message pop-up when its completed.", Browser.Buttons.OK);
  if( !( ss.getSheetByName('EXPORT') ) ) {
    var sheetConfig = ss.getSheetByName('7705-CONFIG');
    var newSheet = sheetConfig.copyTo(ss);
    newSheet.setName('EXPORT');
    var range = newSheet.getDataRange();
    range.setValues(range.getValues());
  }
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("EXPORT");
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  nextLine: for( var i = values.length-1; i >=0; i-- ) {
    for( var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++ )
      if( values[i][j] != "" )
        continue nextLine;
    s.deleteRow(i+1);
  }
  Browser.msgBox("Export Configs Completed", "Your Config File Export is now completed. You can find them on the Google Shared Drive link found on the MAIN Tab Cell H106.", Browser.Buttons.OK);
};
```

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. If you're unsure, please refer to [Stack Overflow Guide on Creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get first column in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895524/get-first-column-in-array)